# How to access array list in getView method

Tags: java, android, twitter, getview

This is part of my adapter code, please help me how can i access the ArrayList within the getView method so that i am able to modify the text in the textview of the layout file.

```
public TweetAdapter(Activity activity,List<Tweet> tweets){

    super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
    List<Tweet> myTweets=tweets;
    inflater=activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // The super.getView is enough to crash the application.
    // Need to understand why it does this.
    //super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tweetTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTweetTitle);
    tweetTitle.setText();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your List in your constructor of Adapter that means you have the list in your Adapter.Just change is like this:

```
List<Tweet> tweets;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Activity activity;
public TweetAdapter(Activity activity,List<Tweet> tweets){

//super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);  remove this line.
this.tweets=tweets;
this.activity = activity;
 inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
```

now you can use `tweets.get(index);` to get you data.Also try using [ViewHolder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) in your adapter.

Change your getView to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // The super.getView is enough to crash the application.
    // Need to understand why it does this.
    //super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown_layout, parent, false);
        TextView tweetTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTweetTitle);
        tweetTitle.setText();

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes 

TextView tweetTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTweetTitle);
  tweetTitle.setText(tweets.get(position).getTitle().toString());

But it gave me a null pointer exception

08-03 15:38:57.136: E/AndroidRuntime(13311):  at com.example.twitterapp.TweetAdapter.getView(TweetAdapter.java:49)

Comment: @user1187878 check now.

Answer (score 0):

You have array list in constructor and position in getView(),so can access array list as following way.

```
class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

private ArrayList<Tweets> mTweetList;

public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets){
    super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
    mTweetList = tweets;
    inflater=activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String data = mTweetList.get(position);  //Access Array List
    TextView tweetTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTweetTitle);
    tweetTitle.setText(data);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
}}
```

Comment: I tried the above code ... and I did it this way ...but the data from list is not getting populated in the activity...
{   tweetTitle.setText(data.getTitle());
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate the row and then get the TextView from the inflated view and set its text.

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
TextView tweetTitle = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTweetTitle);
tweetTitle.setText(data);
return rowView;
```

Edit: Add return rowView instead of inflating the layout again and returning it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this but .. its not populating the data from the array list !!!

> have try this . May be it help you .....

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // The super.getView is enough to crash the application.
    // Need to understand why it does this.
    //super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
    TextView tweetTitle = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTweetTitle);

    Tweet data = mTweetList.get(position);

    tweetTitle.setText(data.getTitle());
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify the title text 
For example

```
 List<Tweet> myTweets;
 public TweetAdapter(Activity activity,List<Tweet> tweets)
 {

    super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
    myTweets = tweets;

    inflater=activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
 {
     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent,false);
    TextView tweetTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTweetTitle);
    tweetTitle.setText(myTweets.get(position).title);

   return convertView;
 }
```

Suppose your Tweet.java class like this for example

```
 class Tweet
 {
      String title;
      Tweet(String title)
      {
           this.title = title;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this link, if it helps you:

https://github.com/codelearn-org/CodelearnTwitterApp/blob/master/src/org/codelearn/twitter/TweetAdapter.java

```
public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {

     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private List<Tweet> tweetsLocal;

     public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tweet> tweets){
         super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
         inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
         tweetsLocal = tweets;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
         View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
         TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);
         Tweet tweet = tweetsLocal.get(position);
         title.setText(tweet.getTitle());
         TextView body = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         body.setText(tweet.getBody());
         return row;
     }

}
```